# Scrapy: downloader/response_count vs response_received_count

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using `scrapy` to crawl multiple websites, and I want to analyze the crawling rate.
The stats dumped at the end contain a `downloader/response_count` value and a `response_received_count` value. The former is systematically greater than the latter.

Why is there a difference and what element of the crawler does increment the two values in the stats collector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `CoreStats` is the [`Extension`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html) responsible for `response_received_count`
- `DownloaderStats` is the [`Middleware`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) responsible for `downloader/response_count`.

`CoreStats` extension is connecting the signal of `signals.response_received` to incrementing the value of `response_received_count`, so it should count every response that you get (even bad statuses), whilst `DownloaderStats` middleware processes the response on a specific order as we can see [here its order is `850`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py#L107), so previous Downloader Middlewares (ones set with a number lower than `850` could drop or even get errors processing the response, and the `downloader/response_count` would never be increased.